# Thread или таймер

Tags: c++, com-port

Каждые 6 секунд получаю данные с АЦП через COMPORT. Как по-вашему лучше (правильнее) оформить: через поток или через компонент Timer прямо в основной программе? Или это примерно одно и то же?

Comment: Платформу укажите.

Comment: Cerbo, С++ Builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, это не одно и то же. Любые операции, требующие задержки, лучше размещать в отдельном потоке, чтобы не было зависаний пользовательского интерфейса. А работа с com-портом однозначно требует задержки независимо от того, сам АЦП выплёвывает данные через каждые 6 секунд, или вы опрашиваете его каждые 6 секунд.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Запрос, получение и обработка данных длится всего около 0.66 сек. А не создает ли таймер свой поток - вот как, наверное, следовало бы задать мой вопрос.

Comment: @BuilderC, это зависит от реализации. Судя по слову "компонент", вы используете Borland (Embarcadero) C++ Builder. Если не ошибаюсь, там таймер не создаёт отдельный поток.